# How to update Room database entry through UI?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, entity

I have an application that allows the user to add Goats with their details such as name, breed, age and gender and additional info. I just created a function in the GoatDao to update the goatInfo parameter and it works inside the Database inspection thing.

```
 @Query("UPDATE goat SET goatInfo=:newInfo WHERE id=:id")
    fun updateInfoByQuery(id: Int, newInfo: String)
```

And this is my Goat entity ˇ

```
@Entity
data class Goat(
    val goatName: String,
    val goatAge: String,
    val goatBreed: String,
    val goatInfo: String,
    val goatGender: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
)
```

I'm stuck on how I could implement the updateInfoByQuery function into UI. I want to have a dialog that launches when a goat is clicked and allows me to update it.

How do I implement that function in the UI?

```
@Composable
fun UpdateDialog(state: GoatState, onDismiss: () -> Unit) {

    val patrick = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.patrick_hand_sc, FontWeight.Black, FontStyle.Normal)
    )


    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() },
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
    ) {
        

 }
}
```

This is my main goat screen code:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun GoatScreen( state: GoatState, onEvent: (GoatEvent) -> Unit) {
    val patrick = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.patrick_hand_sc, FontWeight.Black, FontStyle.Normal)
    )



 


    Scaffold(
        containerColor = colorResource(R.color.brunswick_green),
        topBar = {
            CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    //.padding(6.dp)
                    .shadow(
                        elevation = 5.dp,
                        spotColor = Color.DarkGray,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                    ),
                colors = topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = colorResource(R.color.brunswick_green),
                            titleContentColor = MaterialTheme . colorScheme . primary,
                ),
                title = {

                    Text(
                        "Goats",
                        fontFamily = patrick,
                        color = colorResource(R.color.timberwolf),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        fontSize = 50.sp
                    )


                },

                )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { onEvent(GoatEvent.ShowDialog) }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
            }
        },

    ) {
        padding ->
        if(state.isAddingGoat) {
            AddGoatDialog(state = state, onEvent = onEvent, modifier = Modifier )
        }



        LazyColumn(contentPadding = padding,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp) ) {
            item {
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(8.dp)
                    .shadow(
                        elevation = 5.dp,
                        spotColor = Color.DarkGray,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                    )
                    .background(color = colorResource(R.color.brunswick_green))
                    .horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {
                    SortType.entries.forEach { sortType ->
                        Row(modifier = Modifier.clickable { onEvent(GoatEvent.SortGoats(sortType)) }) {
                            RadioButton(selected = state.sortType == sortType, onClick = { onEvent(GoatEvent.SortGoats(sortType)) }, colors = RadioButtonDefaults.colors(Color.LightGray))
                            Text(text = sortType.name, color = colorResource(R.color.timberwolf))
                        }
                        
                    }

                }

                }


            items(state.goats) {goat ->
                Row(modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(12.dp)
                    .clickable {

                    }
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(color = Color.LightGray, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                    .padding(40.dp)) {



                    Column {
                        Text(text = "${goat.goatName} ${goat.goatAge}", fontFamily = patrick, fontSize = 20.sp
                        )
                    
                        Text(text = "${goat.goatBreed} ${goat.goatInfo}", fontFamily = patrick, fontSize = 20.sp)
                    }


                    
                    IconButton(onClick = { 
                        onEvent(GoatEvent.DeleteGoat(goat)) }) {
                        Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete, contentDescription = "Delete Goat")
                    }
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:
My ViewModel

```
package com.example.goatdatabase

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharingStarted
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.combine
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flatMapLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.stateIn
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.update
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class GoatViewModel(private val dao: GoatDao): ViewModel() {
    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(GoatState())
    private val _sortType = MutableStateFlow(SortType.NAME)
    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    private val _goats = _sortType
        .flatMapLatest { sortType ->
            when(sortType) {
                SortType.NAME -> dao.getGoatsOrderedByName()
                SortType.BREED -> dao.getGoatsOrderedByBreed()
                SortType.AGE -> dao.getGoatsOrderedByAge()
                SortType.GENDER -> dao.getGoatsOrderedByGender()
            }
        }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())
    val state = combine(_state, _sortType, _goats) { state, sortType, goats ->
                state.copy(goats = goats, sortType = sortType) }
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), GoatState())



    fun onEvent(event: GoatEvent) {
        when(event) {
            is GoatEvent.DeleteGoat -> {
                viewModelScope.launch { dao.deleteGoat(event.goat) }
            }
            GoatEvent.HideDialog -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(isAddingGoat = false) }
            }
            GoatEvent.SaveGoat -> {
                val goatName = state.value.goatName
                val goatAge = state.value.goatAge
                val goatBreed = state.value.goatBreed
                val goatInfo = state.value.goatInfo
                val goatGender = state.value.goatGender

                if (goatName.isBlank() || goatAge.isBlank() || goatBreed.isBlank() || goatInfo.isBlank()) {
                    return
                }

                val goat = Goat(goatName = goatName, goatAge = goatAge, goatBreed = goatBreed, goatInfo = goatInfo, goatGender = goatGender)
                viewModelScope.launch { dao.insertGoat(goat) }
                _state.update{it.copy(isAddingGoat = false,
                    goatName = "",
                    goatInfo = "",
                    goatBreed = "",
                    goatAge = ""
                    )}

            }
            is GoatEvent.SetGoatAge -> {
                _state.update {it.copy(goatAge = event.goatAge)}
            }
            is GoatEvent.SetGoatBreed -> {
                _state.update{it.copy(goatBreed = event.goatBreed)}
            }
            is GoatEvent.SetGoatInfo -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(goatInfo = event.goatInfo) }
            }
            is GoatEvent.SetGoatName -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(goatName = event.goatName) }
            }
            GoatEvent.ShowDialog -> {
                _state.update{it.copy(isAddingGoat = true)}
            }

            is GoatEvent.SortGoats -> {
                _sortType.value = event.sortType
            }

            is GoatEvent.SetGoatGender -> {
                _state.update {it.copy(goatGender = event.goatGender)}
            }

           
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT ::::

I updated the view model to launch a dialog for each goat but when I enter data and click save, nothing changes??

```
@Composable
fun UpdateDialog(onEvent: (GoatEvent) -> Unit, state: GoatState, onDismiss: () -> Unit) {

val patrick = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.patrick_hand_sc, FontWeight.Black, FontStyle.Normal)
)
 //   val goat = Goat(state.goatName, state.goatAge, state.goatBreed, state.goatGender, state.goatInfo)


   Dialog(
      onDismissRequest = { onEvent(GoatEvent.HideNewDialog) },
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)

    ) {
        Column {


       TextField( value = state.goatInfo, onValueChange = {onEvent(GoatEvent.SetGoatInfo(it))},
           placeholder = { Text(text = "Goat Info") })

       Button(onClick = { onEvent(GoatEvent.SaveGoat) }) {
           Text(text = "Save")

       }

        }
 }
}
```

This down here is in the view  model:

```
 GoatEvent.ShowNewDialog -> {
                _state.update{it.copy(isUpdatingGoat = true)}
            }

is GoatEvent.UpdateGoatInfo -> {
                dao.updateInfoByQuery(id = state.value.goatId, newInfo = state.value.goatInfo)
            }
```

Comment: Where does the new info come from? I don't see a TextField or anything... Also, we would need to see your the relevant parts of your view model.

Comment: I edited the question to show the view model. As for Text Fields, I didn't implement them in the dialog because I wasn't sure how I'd go about it to reference the function for updating

Comment: Ok. So which of the events should be used for updating the info? I don't see an `UpdateGoat` event. Also, is there a specific reason you dont just replace the entire goat object in the database when it was changed? Yes, there would be a small overhead, but it would be much simpler than having all the boilerplate code to update each single database field separately.

Comment: is GoatEvent.UpdateGoatInfo -> {
                TODO()
            }

Comment: I don't know how to go about using the update function. I'm new to this and documentation didn't get around to helping me.                        How would I go about replacing the entire object?

Comment: Well, so why don't you just replace `TODO()` with `dao.updateInfoByQuery(...)`? Replacing an entry works the same as inserting, you just have to specify the conflict strategy: `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE) fun save(goat: Goat): Long`

Comment: Please check my new edit in the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you have two different approaches

- Directly update a specific field (`goatInfo`) of a `Goat` entity in the database using a custom `@Query` method (`updateInfoByQuery`). That would require specific methods for each field you might want to update, which can lead to boilerplate code if you have many fields or complex entities.
- Replace the entire `Goat` entity using the [`@Insert` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Insert) with `OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE`, as suggested by [Leviathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6216216/leviathan). That does simplify the code by allowing the entire entity to be updated at once if the primary key matches an existing entity in the database.

Make sure your `Goat` entity is set up to be replaced entirely when an existing primary key is detected. That is achieved by specifying a [conflict strategy](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/OnConflictStrategy) in the `@Insert` annotation in your DAO:

```kotlin
@Dao
interface GoatDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun saveGoat(goat: Goat)
    
    // Other DAO methods
}
```

That `saveGoat` method will insert a new `Goat` into the database if the `id` does not exist; if the `id` does exist, it will replace the existing `Goat` with the new one you provide.

To integrate this approach with your UI, especially within the `UpdateDialog`, you would need to make sure your dialog collects not just the `goatInfo`, but potentially any other fields you want to allow the user to update. That might require additional `TextField` components for each field, or just the ones you expect to change frequently.

Modify your `ViewModel` to handle a new event that captures the intent to save or update a goat entity. That involves either creating a new event or repurposing an existing one to carry a complete `Goat` object.

```kotlin
fun onEvent(event: GoatEvent) {
    when(event) {
        is GoatEvent.SaveOrUpdateGoat -> saveOrUpdateGoat(event.goat)
        // Handle other events
    }
}

private fun saveOrUpdateGoat(goat: Goat) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        dao.saveGoat(goat)
        // After saving, you may want to refresh your goat list or perform other UI updates
    }
}
```

When the user completes their updates in the `UpdateDialog` and clicks the save button, collect the updated goat information into a `Goat` object (including the `id` to make sure the database knows this is an update) and trigger the `SaveOrUpdateGoat` event with this object.

---

> I just cannot get my `UpdateDialog` to read the goat Info value (or any other) from the goat that I clicked on.
>
> ```kotlin
> TextField( value = state.goatInfo, onValueChange = 
>  {onEvent(GoatEvent.SetGoatInfo(it))},
>  placeholder = { Text(goat.goatInfo) })
> ```

The `UpdateDialog` is there to allow editing of a goat's details, but the current implementation struggles with displaying the selected goat's `goatInfo` (or other attributes) within the `TextField`.

Modify the state handling in your `ViewModel` to include a property for the currently selected goat. When a goat is selected for editing, this property should be updated to reflect the selected goat. That selected goat's information can then be used to populate the `TextField` values in the `UpdateDialog`.

The `UpdateDialog` should be modified to accept a `Goat` object directly. That way, it can use the properties of this goat object to initialize the `TextField` values.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun UpdateDialog(goat: Goat, onDismiss: () -> Unit, onUpdate: (Goat) -> Unit) {
    var updatedGoatInfo by remember { mutableStateOf(goat.goatInfo) }

    Dialog(onDismissRequest = { onDismiss() }) {
        Column {
            TextField(
                value = updatedGoatInfo,
                onValueChange = { updatedGoatInfo = it },
                label = { Text("Goat Info") },
                placeholder = { Text(goat.goatInfo) }
            )
            // Other TextFields for goatName, goatBreed, etc., as needed
            Button(onClick = { 
                // Create a new Goat object with the updated info to pass back
                val updatedGoat = goat.copy(goatInfo = updatedGoatInfo)
                onUpdate(updatedGoat)
                onDismiss()
            }) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `onUpdate` lambda should trigger an event or function in your ViewModel that updates the goat's information in the database. That part of the solution focuses on using the `copy` function of the data class to create a new `Goat` instance with the updated information, which is then passed back to be saved.

Make sure your `ViewModel` and the event handling mechanism are set up to handle this updated `Goat` object. The event or function triggered by `onUpdate` should result in a database update, either by calling the `saveGoat` method directly (if using `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)`) or by another appropriate mechanism.

---

> How do I tell the view model that it's the specified goat object we're talking about?
>
> **Modify the state handling in your ViewModel to include a property for the currently selected goat. When a goat is selected for editing, this property should be updated to reflect the selected goat.
>
> That selected goat's information can then be used to populate the `TextField` values in the `UpdateDialog`.**

First, you would need a way to keep track of which goat has been selected for editing. That involves adding a property in your `ViewModel` that can hold the currently selected goat. That property can be part of your existing state or a separate `MutableStateFlow` or `LiveData`:

```kotlin
class GoatViewModel(private val dao: GoatDao) : ViewModel() {
    // Assuming GoatState is your UI state class
    private val _selectedGoat = MutableStateFlow<Goat?>(null)
    val selectedGoat: StateFlow<Goat?> = _selectedGoat.asStateFlow()

    // Your existing code
}
```

When a goat is selected (clicked on) in the UI, you should update this `_selectedGoat` property. You can do this by defining an event or function in your ViewModel that sets the selected goat:

```kotlin
fun selectGoat(goat: Goat) {
    _selectedGoat.value = goat
}
```

Now that your ViewModel knows which goat is selected, you can use this information to populate the `UpdateDialog` fields. You will show the `UpdateDialog` when `_selectedGoat` is not null and pass the selected goat to it:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun YourComposable(viewModel: GoatViewModel) {
    // Observing the selectedGoat state
    val selectedGoat by viewModel.selectedGoat.collectAsState()

    // When a goat is selected, show the UpdateDialog
    selectedGoat?.let { goat ->
        UpdateDialog(
            goat = goat,
            onDismiss = { viewModel.selectGoat(null) }, // Clear the selection on dismiss
            onUpdate = { updatedGoat -> 
                viewModel.updateGoat(updatedGoat) // Implement this in ViewModel
            }
        )
    }
}
```

When the "Save" button is clicked in the `UpdateDialog`, the `onUpdate` lambda should trigger a function in your ViewModel that updates the goat's information in the database:

```kotlin
fun updateGoat(updatedGoat: Goat) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        dao.saveGoat(updatedGoat) // Assuming you are using the @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE) strategy
        _selectedGoat.value = null // Optionally clear the selected goat after update
    }
}
```

Your workflow would be:

```bash
User Interface (UI)                     ViewModel                          Database
     |                                      |                                  |
     | --- Select Goat for Editing ------>  |                                  |
     |                                      |                                  |
     |                                      | --- Update _selectedGoat ----->  |
     |                                      |        (MutableStateFlow)        |
     |                                      |                                  |
     | <--- Observe _selectedGoat -------   |                                  |
     |      (Collect as State)              |                                  |
     |                                      |                                  |
     |                                      |                                  |
     | --- Show UpdateDialog with ------->  |                                  |
     |     Selected Goat's Info             |                                  |
     |                                      |                                  |
     |                                      |                                  |
     | --- User Updates Goat Info ------->  |                                  |
     |     and Clicks Save                  |                                  |
     |                                      |                                  |
     |                                      | --- Update Goat in Database -->  |
     |                                      |     (saveGoat/Update Query)      |
     |                                      |                                  |
     |                                      | <--- Optionally Clear ---------  |
     |                                      |     _selectedGoat                |
     |                                      |                                  |
```

1. A goat is selected for editing, updating the ViewModel's `selectedGoat`.
2. The `UpdateDialog` displays, pre-filled with the selected goat's information.
3. Changes made in the dialog are saved back to the database through the ViewModel.

That does illustrate a basic state management and ViewModel patterns but also demonstrates how to manipulate and display dynamic data based on user interaction in a Jetpack Compose application.

Comment: I just cannot get my UpdateDialog to read the goat Info value (or any other) from the goat that I clicked on.   `TextField( value = state.goatInfo, onValueChange = {onEvent(GoatEvent.SetGoatInfo(it))},
               placeholder = { Text(goat.goatInfo) })`